# looking for the most accurate to sort double numbers

Tags: c++, sorting, floating-point

I need to sort small float number.
When I use **std::sort() //algorithm library**,
I found that it's inaccurate in case of very very small numbers.
How can I sort this array in most accurate way?
edit : my friend suggested to me this lines of code which i don't understand them and they seemed don't work properly for the second items in pair

```
bool is_smaller(pair<double,int> a, pair <double , int> b)
{
return (b.first - a.first) > 1e9;
}
sort(a.begin(), a.end(), is_smaller);

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    vector <pair<double,int> > a;
    double x = 0, y = 1, k, d;

    for(int i = 0;i < s.size();i++)
    {
        k = (x + y)/2;
        d = abs(k - y);
        //printf("[%.3lf %0.3lf]  %.3lf %.3lf \n",x, y, k, d);
        a.push_back({k,i+1});
        if(s[i] == 'l')
            y = k, x = k - d;
        else
            y = k + d, x = k;
    }
    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    for (int i =0;i < a.size();i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i].second);


    return 0;
}
```

input : rrlllrrrlrrlrrrlllrlrlrrrlllrllrrllrllrrlrlrrllllrlrrrrlrlllrlrrrlrlrllrlrlrrlrrllrrrlrlrlllrrllllrl
code's output :
1
2
6
7
8
10
11
13
14
15
19
21
23
24
25
29
32
33
36
39
40
42
44
45
50
52
53
51
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
100
49
48
47
46
43
41
38
37
35
34
31
30
28
27
26
22
20
18
17
16
12
9
5
4
3

expected output :
1
2
6
7
8
10
11
13
14
15
19
21
23
24
25
29
32
33
36
39
40
42
44
45
50
52
53
54
55
57
61
63
64
65
67
69
72
74
76
77
79
80
83
84
85
87
89
93
94
99
100
98
97
96
95
92
91
90
88
86
82
81
78
75
73
71
70
68
66
62
60
59
58
56
51
49
48
47
46
43
41
38
37
35
34
31
30
28
27
26
22
20
18
17
16
12
9
5
4
3
comment :wrong answer 28th numbers differ - expected: '54', found: '51'

Comment: Could you post your code ?

Comment: I think your real problem is that your numbers are not "accurate", not with trying to find a "more accurate" sorting method (as there won't be one). Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Are those numbers binary representable or just rounded up/down by a minimum floating point step ?

Comment: @i post the code above.

Comment: And what makes you think that this doesn't sort accurately? Post your input, the actual and expected outputs, and why you expected that output.

Comment: posted input, output, and the expected one

Comment: sorting a `std::pair` orders it by first then second. You are printing out the second value which is why they aren't ordered.

Comment: You are not outputting the sorted doubles at all. How do you know they aren't sorted correctly?

Comment: is there any solution for fixing the compare process?

Comment: The compare process is fine! Your assumption about the `double` stored in the first part of the `pair` is wrong. Print it and see where you failed.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic has limited precision, although this precision is high with doubles, but it is still limited.

You algorithm generates a sequence of numbers, K(i), where
`|K(i+1) - k(i)| = 2^(-i)`.

The |difference| above is a geometric sequence, so it decreases exponentially. Therefore, at some value of `ì`, the difference will become so small that it cannot be reported into the floating-point representation.

I ran your code with exactly the same input, but I also printed the numbers deside the indices, and I did not apply the sorting. I printed the numbers up to 50 decimal digits (`%.50f`, just to see!). What did I observe?

The numbers for positions `i > 53` are all equal (within the precision that the `double` could achieve). Therefore, the numbers indexed above 53 will be sorted somehow randomly, because they are equal.

Comment: until the comparision in the range of indexes 1 to 53 it is correct and when i > 53 it is randomly sorted , it seems like a serious problem is there any simple handling to this ?
please see my last edit to the main post 
thanks

Comment: As long as we are using the IEEE754 standard for double-precision arithmetic (that's what `double` means, using 64 bits representation), we cannot do better for this application. If you want more precision, you need more bits, so you will have to find a library that provides wider floating-point numbers.

Comment: The rule of thumb that I have always used is that float (IEEE-754 4 byte) has approximately 7 significant decimal digits and that double has approximately 15.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein a little more, maybe 18. But the point of printing so many decimal digits is to avoid this calculation and focus on observing the precision problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the floats with enough precision:

```
printf("%03d %.18f\n",a[i].second,a[i].first);
```

then you'll see that the computations lead to the same floating point value for the rank 51 to 100...

Comment: then the problem in the way the numbers is sirted

Comment: Unless the problem lies in the way that two different fractions close enough are rounded to same (nearest) floating point value...

Comment: no it is the problem .

Comment: Then maybe your problem is more about not listening the advices. See the more detailed answer of A.S.H., think again, or maybe execute your program step by step in a debugger in order to get a better understanding.

Comment: i'm afraid that i do't know how to use the debugger